# confirmation mail to unconfirmed mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

When I update the email id in devise like this:

```
current_user.update!(email: params[:email])
```

Email is sent to current email id. I want to send the confirmation email to the new email id which is to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to send an info to the old email but want to send confirmation instructions to the new email, what you're looking for is two settings in `config/initializers/devise.rb`, namely `reconfirmable` and `send_email_changed_notification`. The former sends an email to the new email with confirmation instructions (basically repeating what's happening at initial creation where a confirmation email is sent to the email being used) while the latter sends an info that an email was changed to the old email. Consequently, you need to set the values to `true` and `false` respectively:

```rb
# in config/initializers/devise.rb

Devise.setup do |config|
  # ...

  config.reconfirmable = true
  config.send_email_changed_notification = false
end
```

It could be that these are already in your `devise.rb` – if they are, make sure to set them there to not have them twice and accidentally override each other in ways you don't want.

Comment: `  config.reconfirmable = true
  config.send_email_changed_notification = false` Using this also confirmation mail is sent to old email.

Comment: Did you restart your server, your workers and all these things (including, potentially, `spring stop`)?

Comment: I ran rails s again

Comment: `  config.reconfirmable = true` Using this only also send email to old email

Comment: Could you please help me out in that?

Comment: What do your unit tests say? Do they yield the same strange behavior? Can you share the tests for your user model and the code itself?